_TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String') how can i fix this , i want to display a message on flutter app
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ChatMessages extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChatMessages({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('chat')
          .orderBy(
            'createAt',
            descending: false,
          )
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, chatsnapshots) {
        if (chatsnapshots.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }

        if (!chatsnapshots.hasData || chatsnapshots.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
          return const Center(
            child: Text('No message  found '),
          );
        }
        if (chatsnapshots.hasError) {
          return const Center(
            child: Text('something went wrong'),
          );
        }
        final loadedMessages = chatsnapshots.data!.docs;

        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: loadedMessages.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
              Text(loadedMessages[index].data()['text']),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

I want to display message that I enter from Flutter app. At the Firebase message is updated, but not in app.

I'm not sure I understand the problem. Can you clarify what isn't working about the code you shared? Is there an error message?

It's possible that the error you're encountering is related to accessing the text field within the list builder. Double-check to ensure that the value is not null.
Additionally, when storing chat data in the database, ensure that you're not storing any null values. This can help prevent similar errors in the future.
